# Remove symbol loaded by add-symbol-file

Tags: gdb, embedded

I am debugging U-boot, the code is relocated from internal RAM to DRAM after the DRAM initialization completed. Therefore the image symbol is loaded twice at different locations (in internal RAM address space and in DRAM address space). When I tried to create a breakpoint, gdb added two breakpoints for both address spaces. The problem is the number of hardware breakpoint is limited. Currently, I worked around by removing the older breakpoint in order to add new one. I am finding a way to unload (remove) the symbol file that is loaded in the early stage (symbol that mapped to internal RAM).

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run `symbol-file` without arguments for that:

```
Reading symbols from /tmp/foo...done.
(gdb) symbol-file
Discard symbol table from `/tmp/foo'? (y or n) y
No symbol file now.
(gdb) symbol-file foo
Reading symbols from /tmp/foo...done.
(gdb) symbol-file
Discard symbol table from `/tmp/foo'? (y or n) y
No symbol file now.
```

Answer (score 6):

I worked on a patch for GDB to remove user-added symbol files. It's a new command called
remove-symbol-file:

```
remove-symbol-file FILENAME
remove-symbol-file -a ADDRESS
  Remove a symbol file added via add-symbol-file.  The file to remove
  can be identified by its filename or by an address that lies within
  the boundaries of this symbol file in memory.
```

The patch was merged in GDB's master branch [1] and so should become available in GDB 7.7. You can build GDB from the latest development source in the meantime: https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/current/.

[1] http://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2013-10/msg00891.html